# How to convert string into NSDate format?

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsstring, nsdateformatter

i want to convert the string into nsdate format.

here is my string NSString str=@"Sunday, June 6, 2010 5:00:00 AM CDT";

my code is

```
        NSDateFormatter * Dateformats= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [Dateformats setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm:ss"]; //ex @"MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 
        NSDate *myDate=[Dateformats dateFromString:str];
        NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

but it is displays null so show me the way to display the date in MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm:ss

please friends help me ,how to do this

Comment: What is `k`?   It's undeclared in the code snippet.   Also, the declaration of DateFormats needs to be moved down or over to get into the code block.

Comment: You read the spec on NSDateFormatter and construct a format string to match your input.  But also note you should set the locale of the date formatter to "en_US_POSIX".

Comment: (And, as gaige points out, use the same variable name to both set and access the DateFormatter.)

Comment: (And, standard C++/Objective-C convention is to use names with leading lower-case for variables, leading upper-case for classes.)

Comment: Please Don't Ask Question which ask Before ...

Please [Open this.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311421/converting-a-string-to-an-nsdate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set your formatter to expecting a string like `@"05/26/2012 8:34:00"`. But you give it `@"Sunday, June 6, 2010 5:00:00 AM CDT"`. The two formats are nothing alike. It doesn't know how to parse it and so returns `nil`.

The format you want for the example string you give is `EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a zzz`.

Details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) and [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned your date string: NSString str=@"Sunday, June 6, 2010 5:00:00 AM CDT";

The date format should be like,

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z"];

For more details please go through this one: [DateFormatter Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993578/whats-wrong-with-how-im-using-nsdateformatter)

Try this out, hope it will work for you..

Enjoy coding :)