# Using NSDateFormatter dateFromString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a code :

```
NSString *dateStr = [currentElementValue stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

and i am receiving dates from server as string like :

```
Tue, 08 Jan 2013 13:21:54 +0000
```

but here's my problem , when i use : `[dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]`

```
Mon, 07 Jan 2013 10:31:30 +0000 converted to 07-01-2013
```

but `Wed, 02 Jan 2013 15:12:57 +0000` 
could not be converted.

anyone have any clue why is this happening?

any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Look at the description of the date format string (accessible with a link chain from NSDateFormater description).  You used "hh" when you should use "HH".

Comment: omg! it really solved my problem , just changed hh to HH and it is solved.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, you were quicker! (Haven't seen the comments until posting my answer.) Make it an answer you too.

Comment: and another question here(i am dealing with some rss feeds) : anyone can figure out format of this string : '2013-01-07T08:23:00.001+02:00' ?

Comment: @iremk: `yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993578/whats-wrong-with-how-im-using-nsdateformatter) describes all the format specifiers in detail. `hh` stands for "hour (1-12, zero padded)" - so you can't write `15h` here. If you wish to use a 24-hour time format, use `HH` instead.

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZ"];
```

Comment: and another question here(i am dealing with some rss feeds) : anyone can figure out format of this string : '2013-01-07T08:23:00.001+02:00' ?

Comment: @iremk -- Depends on which iOS version you're targeting.  With older versions you had to remove the final ":" from the string before parsing.  With [iOS 6](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) you can use "ZZZZZ".